# Call AddressBook problem on IPhone platform

Tags: iphone, addressbook

HI all,
   I am puzzled that my program include the lib about ,but it can't call all the method like ABPersonCreate(),ABAddressBookCreate() and so on. The Emulator does not contain the Address book application, so the problem causes by this?  if not, what other info should me provide with?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to reinstall the iPhone Simulator, your problem must be th Address book application.

Comment: I am sorry to ask this question。 I'm a newer.